# why 'ctop command' shows two containers for a single deployment in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment in k8s environment and ran `ctop` command to see memory and cpu utilization.

`NAME             CID                CPU    MEM          NET RX/TX  IO R/W       PIDS
   ◉  k8s_POD_pod1-… c029e2492e7b   0%     1M / 23.54G   0B / 0B    0B / 0B     1
   ◉  k8s_pod1_…     411fc43165fe   6%     23M / 23.54G  0B / 0B    0B / 0B     115`

why there are `k8s_POD_*` and `k8s_*`, two containers for single entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your pod contains a single container, that is why you are asking this question (which is indeed a good question!).

So, one of these containers is the one you actually deployed, but the second one is a Kubernetes infrastructure container, known as a `pause container`.

This `pause container` is the container that holds all the containers of a pod
together. All containers of a pod share the same network and other
Linux namespaces. The pause container is an infrastructure container whose sole
purpose is to hold all these namespaces. All other user-defined containers of the pod then use the namespaces of the pod infrastructure container.

See more details here:
https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container

Answer (score 2):

There is no enough information to give you a concrete answer, but Ill try to speculate.

As Kubernetes works, it needs a base container `pause`, to create the network namespace, to get the network interface and an IP address. Then it adds the additional containers to this network namespace.

That's what you might be seeing.